# How to resolve error while running an executable .bin file?

Tags: server, software-installation, executable, execute-command

I am trying to run an executable '.bin' file. Under ubuntu-server 18.04, I run this command:

```
./pentaho-business-analytics-9.0.0.0-423-x64.bin
```

also tried

```
./pentaho-business-analytics-9.0.0.0-423-x64.bin --mode text
```

In both cases I am getting this error message :

```
Installer payload initialization failed. This is likely due to an incomplete or corrupt downloaded file.
```

Redownload did not resolve the issue.
Is there anything I could try?

N.B. For this specific '.bin' file. The instructions on the source website indicates that the commands above are the way to run.
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.4/0F0/0I0/030

Is there anything I could try?

Comment: Ask at the source site, they might have uploaded a faulty file. Often there are MD5/SHA/other hash values to verify the downloaded file, did you check that?

Comment: I understand there is a `installation-summary.txt` file, is there anything interesting in it?

Comment: @SorenA, I asked at the source site.
For MD5/SHA. I have no idea how to check that. Any hints?

Comment: @Jos, I have the bin file on its own directory. After running. I verified there is no other file there.

Comment: I don't see where I can download this installer, otherwise I would have tried it myself. Do you need an account to access the `.bin` installer?

Comment: @Jos, Yes unfortunately you need an account. You can download from this link: https://www.hitachivantara.com/en-us/products/data-management-analytics/pentaho-platform/pentaho-data-integration/pentaho-trial-download.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a corrupted downloaded '.bin' file.
I had to download the file again 3 times until it finally run.